# Get and set JMeter's properties in Java Request Sampler

Tags: java, jmeter, jsr223

I have been using JSR223 sampler for some java code but now I am implementing Java Request sampler.
The JSR223 code cannot directly work in the Java Request sampler. There are some changes needs to be made. For e.g. in JSR223 the code is:

```
 props.put("p_driver", driver);
 object = props.get("p_driver").getJsonObject(dbser, dbn, wfid);
```

Here the driver is an object of type Driver (a utility class that we have written.

I want to create a property of type Object and keep the driver object in it.
Also I want to get and set different properties through Java.
I know we can use:

```
JMeterContextService.getContext().getCurrentSampler().getProperties("p_driver");
```

But there is very less clarity on how jmeter variables and jmeter properties can work in a Java Request Sampler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [JavaSamplerContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerContext.html) which is Sampler context, it supports only get (read only) operations:

> JavaSamplerContext is used to provide context information to a JavaSamplerClient implementation. This currently consists of the initialization parameters which were specified in the GUI.

Also a Implementation note in code:

> All of the methods in this class are currently read-only.

I see you manage to get property, so this was the intention to read property/variable used in GUI, but not to set/update properties/variables .

Especially will not support update properties which effect multi threads:

> If update methods are included in the future, they should be defined so that a
>         single instance of JavaSamplerContext can be associated with each thread.

Here's kafka example of reading JMeter variables:

[image]

Comment: You mean properties cannot be set in a Java request sampler and can only be get ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [JavaSamplerContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerContext.html).

Use JMeter 4.0 and you'll have access to:

- [javaSamplerContext.getJMeterProperties()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerContext.html#getJMeterProperties()) which allows you to set/get Properties you can then access using ${__P(propName)}, ensure you use it in a Thread-safe way
- [javaSamplerContext.getJMeterVariables()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerContext.html#getJMeterVariables()) which allows you to set/get Variables you can then access using ${varName}, ensure you use it in a Thread-safe way

You can then get Variable or Property through:

> javaSamplerContext.getJMeterProperties().get("propName")
>
> javaSamplerContext.getJMeterVariables().get("varName")

You can then set Variable or Property through:

> javaSamplerContext.getJMeterProperties().put("propName", Object you want)
>
> javaSamplerContext.getJMeterVariables().putObject("varName", Object you want)

Comment: But I can't use $ since I am coding Java request sampler and not jsr223 or beans hell sampler. Right ?